# Convert mp4 to maximum mobile supported MP4 using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I would like to use `ffmpeg` to convert an `mp4` to 'low size' `mp4` ...

I need an `mp4` file with `h263` video and `aac` audio (or some other settings supported by low cost mobile.) My main concern is that the video be playable on most devices.

What would be some possible `ffmpeg` commands to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are numerous ways to encode mp4 videos, and encoding them for mobile devices is even more complex. I'm not sure what you mean by "low cost mobile" do you mean low cost as in the device, or the bandwidth needed to play said video?

Either way, here a post to get you going: [H.264 WEB VIDEO ENCODING TUTORIAL WITH FFMPEG](https://www.virag.si/2012/01/web-video-encoding-tutorial-with-ffmpeg-0-9/)

### Examples

Here are some `ffmpeg` examples from the post ...

> “Standard” web video (480p at 500kbit/s):
>
> **`ffmpeg -i input_file.avi -vcodec libx264 -vprofile high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:480 -threads
>   0 -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k output_file.mp4`**
>
> 360p video for older mobile phones (360p at 250kbit/s in baseline
>   profile):
>
> **`ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -preset slow -b:v 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 500k -vf scale=-1:360 -threads 0
>   -acodec libvo_aacenc -ab 96k output.mp4`**
>
> 480p video for iPads and tablets (480p at 400kbit/s in main profile):
>
> **`ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -vcodec libx264 -vprofile main -preset slow -b:v 400k -maxrate 400k -bufsize 800k -vf scale=-1:480 -threads 0 -acodec libvo_aacenc -ab 128k output.mp4`**
>
> High-quality SD video for archive/storage (PAL at 1Mbit/s in high
>   profile):
>
> **`ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -vcodec libx264 -vprofile high -preset slower -b:v 1000k -vf scale=-1:576 -threads 0 -acodec libvo_aacenc -ab
>   196k output.mp4`**

### Bitrates, scale and profiles ...

From the examples there, some of the key things you might need to pay attention to are ...

`-b:v 500k`

`-b:a 128k`

Those are bitrates of the video `v` and audio `a`, the lower the number the lower the quality but also the better it might 'play' on a low end device.

`scale=-1:480`

That will scale the video down to a smaller size, see more info about that in the post)

`-vprofile baseline`

This seemly odd `baseline` (or another appropriate [profile parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264#Profiles)) can be important when encoding for certain lower-cost (e.g. Android) devices ...

> **Baseline Profile (BP)**
>
> Primarily for low-cost applications that require additional data loss
>   robustness, this profile is used in some videoconferencing and mobile
>   applications. This profile includes all features that are supported in
>   the Constrained Baseline Profile, plus three additional features that
>   can be used for loss robustness (or for other purposes such as
>   low-delay multi-point video stream compositing). The importance of
>   this profile has faded somewhat since the definition of the
>   Constrained Baseline Profile in 2009. All Constrained Baseline Profile
>   bitstreams are also considered to be Baseline Profile bitstreams, as
>   these two profiles share the same profile identifier code value.

Comment: this all conversion, my input and output file is of same format.

Comment: I'm trying to convert an AVI to MP4 with your 360p command but "-acodec libvo_aacenc -ab 128k" is not working, if I replace it with "-acodec copy", it works, Its error is "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height". Should i set more parameters for audio? if yes, what are does params?

Comment: @user1202498 `-acodec copy` will not actually encode your audio at all but instead just copy the audio stream from the old file into the new one. If you have support for `libvo_aacenc` (do you?) you shouldn't have to set anything special. You can also try `-codec:a aac -strict experimental` to use ffmpeg's native aac encoding.

Comment: Thank you very much, all the solutions out there are having outdated parameters

Comment: what about `-movflags +faststart` output option in order to "move some information to the beginning of your file and allow the video to begin playing before it is completely downloaded" — https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#faststartforwebvideo ?

Comment: also `width not divisible by 2 (853x480)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 ffmpeg.exe -i "input.mp4" -vcodec mpeg4 -preset slower -b:v 1000k -vf "scale=640:480,setsar=1,fps=30,pad=640:480:0:0" -acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 22050 -ab 128k "output (480p).mp4"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Yunnosch's point is always important, but it's _especially_ important when there's already an accepted answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?

Answer (score -1):

I found answer,Thanks for help anyway.

```
ffmpeg -i $input_file -s $size $output_file
```

$size : 320X400 or any WidthXHeight

Comment: This does not answer your question. Justin Jenkins' answer was more complete and insightful. The linked blog post also provided more details to answer this complex question of encoding video for mobile devices.

Comment: this just do rotation without any modification ,exactly what i want , i do not wanted the documentation link

Comment: @Susheel: That command line doesn't do rotation at all, it does a resize - without setting codecs or bitrates (which are what the question was asking for).